# Which app services to apply sitecore config patch to in Azure

Tags: sitecore

I am working on improving the performance of a sitecore site by implementing caching.
On my local development site I was able to apply a patch file to change the size of the data and item caches.
Now to do the same on our test environment is where I get confused.  Our test environment is hosted in Azure.  Do I need to apply the same patch on both the Content Delivery and Content Management app services?

Locally, everything is working as intended, I'm just not sure how to proceed with multiple app services in play.

Answer (score 0):

Any changes which are applied to `master` database caches should be applied on Content Management only.

Changes which are not related to `master` database should be applied to both Content Management and Content Delivery.

The reason is that Content Deliver role does not use `master` database and it doesn't have all the `master` database related caches.